# Can only write as root although user seems to have full permissions

Tags: permissions, users, samba, chmod

I am having trouble writing to a samba share from a linux client (a Windows client can read and write just fine). According to ls -la run from the linux client, I should have full permissions:

```
james@Q35-ICH9:~$ ls -la /mnt/
total 8
drwxr-xr-x  3 root  root  4096 Feb 25 09:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root  root  4096 Feb 25 04:39 ..
drwxrwxrwx 61 james james    0 Feb 26 05:39 cloudshare

james@Q35-ICH9:~$ getfacl  /mnt/cloudshare/
getfacl: Removing leading '/' from absolute path names
# file: mnt/cloudshare/
# owner: james
# group: james
user::rwx
group::rwx
other::rwx
```

but:

```
james@Q35-ICH9:~$ touch  /mnt/cloudshare/test
touch: cannot touch '/mnt/cloudshare/test': Permission denied
```

But if I use sudo, I can touch:

```
james@Q35-ICH9:~$ sudo touch  /mnt/cloudshare/test
```

The user also has full access to the parent folder:

```
james@Q35-ICH9:~$ ls -la /mnt/
total 8
drwxrwxrwx  3 james james 4096 Feb 25 09:38 .
drwxr-xr-x 24 root  root  4096 Feb 25 04:39 ..
drwxrwxrwx 61 james james    0 Feb 26 07:42 cloudshare
```

I am confused as to why I need to be root to write to cloudshare even though 'james' should have full permissions (as far as I can see).

Comment: What is the output if you run `grep /mnt /proc/mounts`? The answer may include your IP address; feel free to hide it. But any other mount options would be important in understanding this problem.

Comment: ```//10.0.0.x/cloud /mnt/cloudshare cifs rw,relatime,vers=1.0,cache=strict,username=neon,domain=,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=10.0.0.x,soft,unix,posixpaths,serverino,mapposix,acl,rsize=1048576,wsize=65536,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1 0 0```

Comment: Did you try removing `noforceuid` and changing `uid=0` to `uid=1000` (or whatever `id -u` tells you is james' user id) (and the same for group)? Also, please [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/503132/edit) the question to put the `mount` output into it!

Comment: Where are these options? I don't seem them in smb.conf.

Comment: They're part of [mount.cifs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/readme/Documentation-filesystems-cifs-README). Try just adding 'uid=1000,gid=1000' to the options in your `fstab` and re-mounting?

Comment: Yes, that did it! Please post it as an answer so that I can properly credit you @drewbenn.
Also, I still have no idea WHY that worked, so feel free to include some explanation when you answer.

Answer (score 3):

Your mount options include `username=neon`, indicating that the connection to the share has been established using that username.

You've presented no reason to assume that the local user `james` would be in any way related to Samba server user `neon`... or to the server user `james` for that matter. Has such a relation been established in some other way?

The SMB protocol always carries the domain information in usernames, and if no other domain is specified, the local hostname is usually used in its place.

So, the files you see as already owned by "james" are actually probably owned by "james@10.0.0.x", which is not necessarily have anything to do with "james@Q35-ICH9".

If "james@Q35-ICH9" does not currently map to any valid user on the Samba server, but "root@Q35-ICH9" does, that might explain the problem you're having.

I also see `vers=1.0` in the mount options, indicating that you're still using the deprecated and WannaCry-vulnerable SMB/CIFS 1.0 protocol. If your Samba server and Windows client are even somewhat up to date, they both should support higher protocol versions. The fact that the version number is reported here indicates that your CIFS mount module also supports higher protocol versions, but might not autonegotiate them if you are using an old Linux distribution.

Alternatively, you may have forced the protocol version to 1.0 deliberately at some point. Please review whether such forcing is still necessary, and if at all possible, please move to newer protocol versions, which will both perform better and be more secure.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up about the version. I don't remember doing that deliberately, but it's possible that I did in the course of troubleshooting and then forgot. Since this is all on a local home network, I'm not really stressing about security.
Regarding the connection between "james@Q35-ICH9' and the neon account, in fstab of james@Q35 I have:
```//10.0.0.8/cloud /mnt/cloudshare cifs rw,vers=1.0,username=neon,password=xxxxx,iocharset=utf8, 0 0```

I thought that was all I had to do. There is currently no 'james' account on 10.0.0.x (the server), just Q35.

Comment: Also, I ran ```chmod -R 777``` on the shared folder on the host. This allowed me to read and write from a Windows computer, but not the Linux one, which is why I am thinking the problem is on the neon client.